# My external IP on Azure Kubernetes Service doesn't work

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have created a kubernetes cluster on Azure. I have deployed some pods where there is no frontend (micro services).

I have performed tests locally using Postman and VS Code: these micro services return either 200 O` or 500.

The problem is that in Kubernetes I have the external IP correctly, but it is impossible for me to access from outside.

I have another Mongo container that I can access without problems.I leave some images to try to solve:

[image]
[image]

Can you help me? thanks!!

Comment: How did you expose the pods, are you using a Service of type LoadBalancer?

Comment: Hi @Thomas thanks for your answer. Yes I use LoadBalancer in the YAML file.

Comment: Can you provide the deployment or pod definition and the service definition yaml? (You can just edit the question and add the information)

Comment: apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web-deployment
  labels:
    app: web-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: web
        image: myacr.azurecr.io/web-container:latest
        command: [ "sleep" ]
        args: [ "infinity" ]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6062

Comment: apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: web
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 6062
  type: LoadBalancer

Comment: That looks right - did you query for the IP of the load balancer (kubectl get services ) and use that IP to access the service?

Comment: Yes, I did that. In MongoDB really I have no problem, I can access without problems from outside the cluster through the external IP. The others, even without having a front, should give me a 200 OK message or a 404 in Postman.
I do not know what it could be.

Comment: What is the error message you get? Do you use "http" as scheme in postman? Do you have a proxy server configured?

Comment: The message is : Could not get any response There was an error connecting to . No i don't have any proxy server configured

Comment: Can you access the port from inside the cluster? (use kubectl exec to run a busybox f.e. and try from there) If that works: Are you sure the port is not firewalled from your company network?

Comment: this is the result: kubectl exec -it --namespace=default permis-deployment-64769f7b87-t5wxx bash
root@permis-deployment-64769f7b87-t5wxx:/app#

Is that what you said?

Comment: you would then need to access the service - f.e. using `curl` and the name of your service, this should be `web-service`

Comment: sorry @Thomas but i don't understand the last step. I try to do it like this: kubectl exec -it --namespace=default permis-deployment-64769f7b87-t5wxx bash
root@permis-deployment-64769f7b87-t5wxx:/app# curl permis-service 

But i don't have any response it goes blank and does nothing.

Comment: The manifest you provided says the service is `web-service` not `permis-service`. So you would need to `curl http://web-service:6062`

Comment: the result: kubectl exec -it --namespace=default web-deployment-789b57b598-dzgb6 bash
root@web-deployment-789b57b598-dzgb6:/app# curl http://web-service:6062
curl: (7) Failed to connect to web-service port 6062: Connection refused

Comment: Looks like your pod is not providing a service on the port 6062 - is your application configured properly? How did you perform the local tests that were successful?

Comment: This is the dockerfile:
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
CMD npm start
EXPOSE 6060

Comment: Your dockerfile states port 6060 not port 6061 - you need to fix your service definition in that case and map port 6062 to 6060 and fix your deployment or fix the node service and the docker file. How did you do the local testing? didn't you use a local docker container?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You will really see there are 4 microservices, one points to 6060 - 6061 - 6062 - 6063 respectively. Each microservice has one of those associated ports in the EXPOSE. In local we have used the docker container as indications and it gives us an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes is a little bit more complex than simple docker containers, so it might get confusing to get it running at first. I will explain at which points you need to configure exposure of a service.

Each container has an own ip address space, so each container can use the same port for an application. In your case you might want to use port 6060. This is the port the application needs to bind to and on all network interfaces (ip 0.0.0.0) to be reachable from the outside. This is the port you would declare as EXPOSE in your dockerfile.

When testing locally you can map each container to a different **local** port for testing: `docker run -p external-port:internal-port`

The port you use for EXPOSE is the port you configure as `containerPort` in a Pod or Deployment.

One or many pods are exposed as load balanced service inside kubernetes using a Service. There you might want to map a request port - for http usually 80 - to the container port, in your case 6060.

The service can then be exposed externally using a LoadBalancer. The external IP of the LoadBalancer will be mapped to the (virtual IP) of your Service, the Service maps the request port to the container port and selects an appropriate pod using the selector. The pod contains a container listening on the container port and then replies to your request.

The whole chain must be configured correctly in order to get it working. Keeping it simple (not using different ports for each application) makes it easier to get right.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it would be viable if it were something with a frontend. We are working in microservices and for now, I should show X information without a frontend as such.

From what I have understood, I have everything correct but I still do not see the explanation to this case.

Comment: Make sure that the ports match (inside the container listening port of the node application, docker file EXPOSE port should always match the listening port!), if that is fixed, change your deployment to not issue a 'sleep' as command, but simply leave it empty and use the CMD from the dockerfile which should start your npm process. If that is all fixed, it should work :)

Comment: If I remove the 'sleep' argument it simply gives me an image error: Warning BackOff 7s (x4 over 37s) kubelet, aks-agentpool-29153703-2 Back-off restarting the failed container

Comment: That is a different kind of problem, not related to the ports. You can open a separate question for that.

Comment: Yes, I will open another for this problem. But what worries me most is that having an exposed IP with an exposed port is not able to show absolutely anything.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to hit restApi URIs like

```
ExternalIP:Port/uri
```

This should be accessible, I also use this approach with AKS

Comment: Can you tell me where I should put this? I do not get it. :s

Comment: Well, you can test this with postman only,the external IP is accessible from everywhere

Comment: Yes, in localhost:Port/uri Works. But in Azure with LoadBalancer not

Comment: this shouldn't happen, can you share the external IP for webservice running on port 6062 and the URI you are appending with it

Comment: This error appears in any of the 4 microservices. This for example: 40.119.128.138:6060  should give a 200 or a 404. If in local we put localhost: 6060 / permission list all the permissions

Answer (score 0):

As I see from your question and the YAML file in your comment, the possible reason as I think is that you set the command in your deployment container, this command will overwrite the default command in the image. So I doubt maybe your application does not start, you can take a check.

I will also suggest you check if the port you expose to the outside is the same as the port in the image.

Comment: Hi, I tried to do what you said, but I had no luck.

In my Dockerfile I have the following:
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
CMD npm start
EXPOSE 6060

as you can see, there is exposed the 6060 port of that microservice (each microservice has a specific port)

Comment: apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: permis-deployment
  labels:
    app: permis-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: permis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: permis
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: permis
        image: myacr.azurecr.io/permission-container:latest
        command: [ "sleep" ]
        args: [ "infinity" ]
-
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: permis-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: permis
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 6060
  type: LoadBalancer

Comment: @LluísLópez I think you do not need to set the command in the container, then add the `targetPort` in the service ports.

Comment: @LluísLópez I want to know why you set the command in the container to "sleep"? What does it use to?

Comment: I have put the TargetPort into service at 6060 and the command as the args I must put it so that the service does not stop

Comment: @LluísLópez What service do you start in the image? Do you run the image successfully in local? I'm afraid your service does not run well.

Comment: This service starts a battery of permits that is linked to another user microservice. I have no problems at home. I will try to change the port since 6060 is occupied by Microsoft from what I have seen and maybe it conflicts.

Comment: It still doesn't work. It has been tested without CMD, then with CMD in Dockerfile. Changing the port in dockerfile and in YAML. The container runs Running gives IP in the LoadBalancer, but there is no response.

Comment: @LluísLópez Do you mind providing the code and Dockerfile to me? I could take a test for you.

Comment: @LluísLópez What about the situation now? Do you solve the problem?

Comment: Hi @Charles-xu i can't provide the code and dockerfile. I'm trying to resolve the problem, but i don't know the next step to solve it

Comment: @LluísLópez I just doubt if your application all run fine. And maybe you do not need to run the command in the YAML file.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to lift one of the 4 microservices.

I have tried to lift the three remaining microservices with the same YAML (changing the image URL and the port) and these do not work.

The YAML used is this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: permissions
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: permissions
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: permissions
        image: URL IMAGE
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6060
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: nameimage
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: permissions
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 6060
  selector:
    app: permissions
```

I added this to set resource limits for the others Microservices:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: users
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: users
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: users
        image: URL IMAGE
        resources:
          requests:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6061
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: users
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 6061
  selector:
    app: users
```

As I said, I could only lift the first one.

Some help?

Thanks!